# Unable to see the UI while using USB modem

Tags: installation, boot, encryption, usb-modem

I successfully installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my system. However, when I tried installing my USB modem of the type ZTE AC2787, I found that the file explorer couldn't detect the modem. Additionally, I couldn't see the UI popping up just like it does in Windows. I checked this website http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2110075 and I tried to look for my modem type in the rules, but I didn't find an entry corresponding to it. I need the UI to check how much data I am consuming. Is there any way to fix this?

Secondly, after I installed Ubuntu on a separate partition I checked for it on Windows, but the drive I installed it on, merely showed it to be an unformatted drive. Now, I remember doing two things. One, while installing, I chose /dev/sda5 as the device to install it on, and then I encrypted my drive. Is this happening because of that? Also, the boot manager still doesn't seem to have a record of Ubuntu because every time I want to boot Ubuntu, I have to press F9 at startup and boot it manually. Is there something I can do here?

As I said before, I am new to Ubuntu, and I am still finding my way to do things. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as the manufactures don't expressly support linux you won't see any GUI for installation. In fact this Windows behaviour might be a reason for your problem. The modem is capable of appearing either as CD or as modem. An within that CD part there is the Windows installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your manufacturer  does not support linux you won't get any GUI but for monitoring your data you can use modem-manager which is available in software center.
[image: Install via the software center]

In windows ubuntu partitions appear to be unformatted because windows doesn't recognise ext4 format partitions.
And finally about boot repair you can use boot-repair.
Instructions on how to get it and how to use it are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).
To install from terminal

Open the terminal and run the following comamnds

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxonly/modem+manager+gui
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install modem-manager-gui
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I realize that the file systems aren't compatible. However, Software Center on my system couldn't locate the application you linked me to, and I don't know how else to open and install it. http://i39.tinypic.com/53wza1.png Would you mind telling me how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got Modem Manager GUI installed. I suppose this is the way any package is installed on Ubuntu? What is "ppa" and what is the purpose of "linuxonly"? Also what commands do I use if I want to update a particular pre - installed package using the terminal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also having another problem. The system recognizes the USB modem, and I can connect to the internet, but whenever I click on the internet connections icon in the tray, It shows "label empty". Also, the GUI doesn't recognize the connection, even though it is registered with the operator MTS. The activation was done on a Windows system though. I don't think that has anything to do with this, does it? Is there any way to fix this?